# Segmentation Faults With my First Come First Serve Scheduling Algorithm

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program to simulate a scheduling algorithm (FCFS). The program takes an input, a `txt` file that contains the following information:

```
# Number of Processes
#PID #CPUTime #IOTime #ArrivalTime
```

An example of an input file is as follows:

```
3
0 2 2 0
1 2 1 5
2 2 1 2
```

I'm trying to write a program that takes this process metadata, and simulates a FCFS algorithm. Each process runs for 1/2 * CPU Time, blocks for IO time, then runs for another 1/2 * CPU Time. The desired output here is:

```
0 0:running
1 0:blocked
2 0:blocked
3 0:running 2:ready
4 2:running
5 1:running 2:blocked
6 1:blocked 2:running
7 1:running
```

I've got the following at the moment, minimized for reproducibility:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Process;
struct MyCustomQueue;

void fcfs(int, FILE);

void enqueue(struct MyCustomQueue *, struct Process *);
struct Process *dequeue(struct MyCustomQueue *);
struct Process *peek(struct MyCustomQueue *queue);

struct Process {
    int processID;
    int cpuTime;
    int ioTime;
    int arrivalTime;
    int cpu_half_1;
    int cpu_half_2;
    bool ready;
    bool running;
    bool blocked;
    bool completed;
    struct Process *next;
};

struct MyCustomQueue {
    struct Process *front;
    struct Process *tail;
    int size;
};

void enqueue(struct MyCustomQueue *queue, struct Process *process) {
    if (queue->size == 0) {
        queue->front = process;
        queue->tail = process;
    } else {
        queue->tail->next = process;
        queue->tail = process;
    }
    queue->size++;
}

struct Process *dequeue(struct MyCustomQueue *queue) {
    if (queue->size == 0) {  
        return NULL;
    } else {
        struct Process *process = queue->front;
        queue->front = process->next;
        queue->size--;  
        return process;
    }

}

struct Process *peek(struct MyCustomQueue *queue) {
    if (queue->size == 0) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return queue->front;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  
    FILE * fp; // for creating the output file
    char filename[100] = ""; // the file name

 
    //Check that the file specified by the user exists and open it
    if (!(fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
        printf("Cannot open file %s\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);    
    }

    int num_processes; // the number of processes
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &num_processes); // read the number of processes

    fcfs(num_processes, *fp);
    
    // Close the processes file
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

void fcfs(int num_processes, FILE fp) {
    struct Process processes_array[num_processes];
    struct MyCustomQueue ready_queue = {NULL, NULL, 0};

    // Add each process to the array
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
        int processID, cpuTime, ioTime, arrivalTime;
        fscanf(&fp, "%d %d %d %d", &processID, &cpuTime, &ioTime, &arrivalTime);
        struct Process process = {processID, cpuTime, ioTime, arrivalTime, ceil(0.5*cpuTime), ceil(0.5*cpuTime), false, false, false, false, NULL};
        processes_array[i] = process;
    }

    // Sort the array by arrival time, and if there is a tie, sort by process ID.
    for (int a = 0; a < num_processes; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < num_processes - 1; b++) {
            if (processes_array[b].arrivalTime > processes_array[b + 1].arrivalTime) {
                struct Process temp = processes_array[b];
                processes_array[b] = processes_array[b + 1];
                processes_array[b + 1] = temp;
            } else if (processes_array[b].arrivalTime == processes_array[b + 1].arrivalTime) {
                if (processes_array[b].processID > processes_array[b + 1].processID) {
                    struct Process temp = processes_array[b];
                    processes_array[b] = processes_array[b + 1];
                    processes_array[b + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int cycle = 0;
    int completed_processes = 0;
    struct Process *current_process = malloc(sizeof(struct Process));
    struct Process default_process = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, false, false, false, false, NULL};
    current_process = &default_process;

    while (completed_processes < num_processes) {

        printf("%d ", cycle);

        // Go through processes_array and check if any processes have arrived. If they have, enqueue them.
        for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
            if (processes_array[i].arrivalTime == cycle) {
                enqueue(&ready_queue, &processes_array[i]);
            }
        }

        // Go through the processes_array and check all processes that marked as blocked. If they are done with their IO time, mark them as ready.
        // Otherwise, print "%d:blocked" for the process.
        for (int i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
            if (processes_array[i].blocked) {
                if (processes_array[i].ioTime == 0) {
                    processes_array[i].blocked = false;
                    processes_array[i].ready = true;
                    processes_array[i].completed = false;
                    processes_array[i].running = false;
                    enqueue(&ready_queue, &processes_array[i]);
                } else {
                    printf("%d:blocked ", processes_array[i].processID);
                }
            }
        }

        // If the current process is not assigned, assign it to the first process in the ready queue.
        if (current_process->processID == -1) {
            current_process = dequeue(&ready_queue);
            current_process->ready = false;
            current_process->running = true;
            current_process->blocked = false;
            current_process->completed = false;
            printf("%d:running ", current_process->processID);
        }

        // Print the ready queue, not including the process already running.
        struct Process *current = ready_queue.front;
        while (current != NULL) {
            printf("%d:ready ", current->processID);
            current = current->next;
        }

        // Scheduling Logic
        // A Process takes up `cpu_half_1` cycles to complete the first half of its CPU time.
        // Then it is blocked for IO time.
        // Then it takes up `cpu_half_2` cycles to complete the second half of its CPU time.
        // Then it is completed.

        if (current_process->cpu_half_1 > 0) {
            current_process->cpu_half_1--;
        } else {
            current_process->cpu_half_2--;
        }

        if (current_process->cpu_half_1 == 0) {
            // First Half done - block for IO
            if (current_process->ioTime > 0) {
                current_process->blocked = true;
                current_process->running = false;
                current_process->ready = false;
                current_process->completed = false;
            }
            // Second Half done - complete
            if (current_process->cpu_half_2 == 0) {
                current_process->blocked = false;
                current_process->running = false;
                current_process->ready = false;
                current_process->completed = true;
                completed_processes++;
            }
            current_process = &default_process;
        }       

        printf("\n");
        // completed_processes++;
        cycle++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The output I get is (run with lldb)

```
0 0:running 
1 
2 0:blocked 1:running 
3 0:blocked 2:ready 
4 0:blocked 2:ready 
5 0:blocked 1:blocked 2:running 
6 0:blocked 1:blocked 
7 0:blocked 1:blocked 
8 0:blocked 1:blocked 
Process 57668 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003a3c scheduling`zero(num_processes=3, fp=FILE @ 0x000000016fdfef80) at scheduling.c:237:36
   234          // If the current process is not assigned, assign it to the first process in the ready queue.
   235          if (current_process->processID == -1) {
   236              current_process = dequeue(&ready_queue);
-> 237              current_process->ready = false;
   238              current_process->running = true;
   239              current_process->blocked = false;
   240              current_process->completed = false;
Target 0: (fcprogram) stopped.
```

So both the output so far is undesired, and the segmentation fault is confusing me.

Comment: You might consider putting together a [mcve] that uses hardcoded data the make debugging easier. It would also allow others to be able to run your code and perhaps help to narrow down the issue. I'd focus either on the crash or the output but not both at once.

Comment: "I'm running into a lot of segmentation faults though and I'm really unsure on how to proceed" use a debugger like gdb .  that will tell you *where* the segfault occurred, which takes the guesswork out of debugging.

Comment: I used lldb, and it's pointing to lines where current_process is used, so I'm thinking it's the way I initialized current_process. Still running into issues where the output is undesired. @RetiredNinja Let me update the post with sample Input

Comment: If gdb doesn't work/ is insufficient use -fsanitize=address or valgrind.

Comment: I'd still have to invent far too much code to run this, so it isn't a [mcve].

Comment: Ah, I understand. I just entirely edited the post again. This is the most minimal I could make the code, while still having each part of my algorithm included and including feedback from the comments.

Comment: I made some changes to read from `stdin` and avoid the crash caused by `current_process == NULL` after this line `current_process = dequeue(&ready_queue);` It doesn't crash but there's an endless loop of all the processes blocked for you to figure out. One thing to note, *never* pass `FILE` structures by value, just pass the pointer. In the case of using `stdin` it just crashes, but with a regular file pointer you're making a copy of a deliberately opaque struct that is only ever meant to be used as a pointer then making a pointer to the local parameter copy. Anyway, just don't do that.

Comment: Link to changes: https://godbolt.org/z/jPGnxxPaj

Comment: Ah, I see I need to check for a front of the queue to dequeue, otherwise the value is null and hence the segmentation fault, thanks! Going to try to figure out the output problems now

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems:

- You should ALWAYS check the return value from fscanf().  For example:

  ```
  if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &num_processes) != 1) {
      <<error handling >>
  ```
- You should check `argc` before accessing argv[], and print the same value as your filename (either argv[1] or argv[2]):

  ```
  if (!(fp = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
      printf("Cannot open file %s\n", argv[2]);
      exit(1);    
  }
  ```
- Thank you for including the stack trace - that's extremely helpful!  But...

  Q: Which line in your code is it crashing on?  Which statement corresponds to "scheduling.c:237:36"?

  Q: Have you stepped through the debugger, set a breakpoint at line 237, and examined the variables yet?

---

OK:

Thank you for your update.  A couple of additional problems:

- Delete the line `struct Process *current_process = malloc(sizeof(struct Process));`: it's a memory leak.
  You're ALREADY doing this, so you don't NEED the extraneous line/unnecessary "malloc()" anyway:

  ```
  struct Process default_process = {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, false, false, false, false, NULL};
  struct Process *current_process = &default_process;
  ```
- I suspect this is why you're crashing:

  ```
  // If the current process is not assigned, assign it to the first process in the ready queue.
  if (current_process->processID == -1) {
      current_process = dequeue(&ready_queue);
      // <-- So what happens if dequeue() returns NULL?
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response! To address the `fscanf` and `argc` comments, I do have them in my code, just not in the code here to try to minimize the amount of code I posted. Seems like the line is `current_process->ready = false;`, where i check if no process is running (ie current process is set to default_process)

Comment: 1) None of the code you posted has the line `current_process->ready = false;`  2) It sounds like you never initialized "current_process" before calling that function!  3) The Debugger is your Friend :)  Step through the code.  Ensure everything is correctly initialized; ensure  everything is set to "reasonable" values.

Comment: Ah, maybe you caught it inbetween edits? I have it initalized. Thanks for the heads up on the debugger, I'll watch a tutorial on getting that set up

Comment: If the edits were made after the close, then add a re-open vote to mine. (it looks like that was the sequence, and the contents here now meet the MRE requirement)

Comment: I can't vote to re-open, but still having this issue. Struggled with the debugger and couldn't pinpoint the issue, so I'm back to the start to try to debug this

Comment: I voted to re-open ... but that probably isn't going to help :(
Q: Did you see my update about "dequeue()", and what action are you now taking if it returns NULL?  Q: What did you learn in the debugger?

Comment: Ah, yes I see your point about the dequeue, I learned that somehow my value can be NULL, hence the segmentation fault. Thanks for the heads up, I fixed the conditional to check if the queue has a ready struct as well to use (per a comment's suggestion). In terms of now getting the desired output, I'm going to take a deeper look at it, do you see any glaring problems as to why I may be getting an incorrect output? Thanks for the help!